# C# JSON-Convert doesn't work with tuples

Tags: c#, .net, json, tuples

Creating a .Net web API I'm serializing an object including a list of tuples (`List<Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>`):

Returning the tuple as JSON (JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myTuple)) from my controller, the following format gets returned:

`[{Item1: datetime, Item2: datetime}]`

But when I want to send the information back, it only works with the following format:

`[{m_Item1: datetime, m_Item2: datetime}]`

What can I do to unify the format?

Comment: Works fine for me... https://dotnetfiddle.net/LDKFeX

Comment: Does it work for you with "Item1" or "m_Item1"?

Comment: Did you look at the link I gave you?

Comment: @Archer you didn't specify type to which it should be deserialized, but it still works: https://dotnetfiddle.net/8nlxkC

Comment: @KrzysztofSkowronek Correct - I was just making the point that there is no difference between the properties before and after serialization.  Either way, the OP needs to explain more.

Comment: @Archer thank you for that example. Really interesting. Do you know where the deserialization takes place using the .NET Web API? There I only have a paramter "[FromBody] myObject" ...

Comment: Can you elaborate?  Are you calling a controller method in C# and serializing and passing the tuple as a post parameter?  I think you'll need to post some code showing how you send and receive data, as there's not enough here to be clear about what's happening.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I found a solution in this block [link](https://forums.asp.net/t/1821729.aspx?JsonMediaTypeFormatter+does+not+work+with+Tuple+int+List+string+). That works for me. It seems that there is a problem with the serialization attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this forum [Link](https://forums.asp.net/t/1821729.aspx?JsonMediaTypeFormatter+does+not+work+with+Tuple+int+List+string+) there are problems with the serialization.

Adding following snippet to the *App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs* solved that problem:

`config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver =new DefaultContractResolver();`